# Is using ", right?" at the end of a question aggressive or could be read as such?

Tags: word-usage, difference, connotations

Is using ", right?" at the end of a sentence aggressive or could be read as such?

For example:

> What you say is that the project should be finished tomorrow**, right**?

Could this "right?" at the end of the sentence be understood or read as aggressive?

Would it be better to use this other sentence:

> What you say is that the project should be finished tomorrow, don't you?

Is this second sentence better? Why? What are the differences between both?

Comment: It would depend on the tone of voice, but "Right?" could sound confrontational. "What you say is....., isn't it?" would be better than "don't you?" But if it's said in a questioning tone you don't really need to add anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear aggressive to me. It is a reduced form of "Is that right?". It could be spoken in a way that is aggressive. If you say that while standing over me, looking down and jabbing your finger in my face it would be aggressive! But there is nothing aggressive in the words themselves.

The second sentence doesn't work well.  In both cases, I would use "What you're saying..."  (this isn't what you *always* say). So the tag question would be

> What you're saying is that the project should be finished tomorrow, aren't you?

Perhaps I'm *splitting hairs*, but for me, the meaning of this is different.  This is asking if these were the words that the person spoke. On the other hand. The "Is that right?" question asks if the project will be finished tomorrow.  It is checking the opinion of the person, not just the meaning of the words that the person spoke.